# Why I cant change list value by lambda expression in Python?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a list:

```
goods = [True, False, True, True, False, True, False]
```

I need to invert some values by indexes, as example: 1, 3, 4
This means goods[1] will be True, goods[3] - False, goods[4] - True.
If I do it in map + lambda I catch error like this:

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

list(map(lambda x: goods[x]=True if goods[x] is False else True, [1, 3, 4]))
```

Why I cant change list value in such case?

Comment: The conditional expression (X if Y else Z) requires *expressions* for each component. `goods[x]=True` is not an expression; it's an assignment statement. If you're trying to alter the contents of `goods` in place, putting an assignment inside `map` is not a viable way to do it.

Comment: You could just write a straight for-loop.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to abuse comprehensions (or collections) for side effects. Why not simply:

```
for x in [1, 3, 4]:
    goods[x] = not goods[x]
```

If, for some misguided sense of aesthetics, one were desperate to use a lambda function, you would have to use it to rebuild the `goods` themselves (lambdas may only contain a single expression, not a statement where an assignment is a statement):

```
goods[:] = map(lambda x: not x[1] if x[0] in [1, 3, 4] else x[1], enumerate(goods))
```

There is nothing graceful about that though =)

Comment: This is simpler and the correct way to do it. +1

Comment: And if it *must* be a one-liner, just do `for x in [1, 3, 4]: goods[x] = not goods[x]` xD

Comment: Agree, this is simpler and easy way to do it. But is there the way make it by lambda etc?  I would like do it more gracier if it possible. How do you think? String like this for x in [1, 3, 4]: goods[x] = not goods[x] look well, but not whole in PIP8

Comment: I added an option. Why anyone would associate lambdas and grace, however, is beyond me ;-)

Comment: Yes, look not very simple) Left first variant)

Answer (score 0):

If [numpy](https://numpy.org/) is an option, possibly something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

goods = np.array([True, False, True, True, False, True, False])
goods[[1,3,4]] ^= True     # xor to flip booleans
print(goods)   # [True  True   True  False True   True  False]
```